# Compilable modern alternatives to C/C++

Tags: programming-languages, performance

I am considering writing a new software product. Performance will be critical, so I am wary of using an interpreted or language or one that uses a emulation layer (read java).

Which leads me to thinking of using C (or C++) however these are both rather long in the tooth. I haven't used either for a long time. I figured in the last 20 years someone has probably created something which is reasonably popular, nice to code in and compiled.

What more modern alternatives are there to C for writing high performance compiled code?

If C++ is a different beast than it was 15 years ago, I would consider it, I guess I had an assumption that it had some inherent problems.

Parallelisation would be important, but probably not across multiple machines.

Comment: Modern C++ is radically different than C.  It's much more comparable to something like Java or C# than it is to C, except it features deterministic destruction instead of garbage collection, and also has undefined behavior since it doesn't run in a VM or managed environment.  Your other alternative is D, which is a decent language, but still very immature in terms of libraries and support.

Comment: what is your idea about parallelization? Do you think your software needs concurrent and/or distributed architecture?

Comment: For some languages that you might be avoiding because they are interpreted, there are often compilers to convert your program into native machine code. Just a thought...

Comment: Keep in mind that performance is never equally critical across the board. There are always parts which are more performance-critical than others. For example, as soon as you consider UI-code, you can usually ignore the performance difference between Java and C++.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "performance will be critical" part? Why will it be critical? Have you measured anything yet?

Comment: 15 years is an eon in computer terms and for as long as that, people like Ericsson have been using *functional languages* like [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) to support distributed, fault-tolerant, soft-real-time, non-stop applications in their embedded systems! Don't assume only C++ can give you the performance you want, you may be better off throwing more hardware at the problem and saving yourself a lot of implementation time with another language.

Comment: @Mark Booth "Don't assume only C++ can give you the performance you want", dude that is why I am asking the question :)

Comment: @JeremyFrench: but you're asking question based on false assumption, that performance => static compilation.

Comment: please, expand problem definition. What will 'critcal' part of code do? Numercal calculation, async. io, text analysis or something else?

Comment: Who wants to bet the performance of the new software product won't be _that_ critical after all? :P

Comment: For what it’s worth, Haskell currently serves as my replacement for C++ in most cases.

Comment: Why no comment on the nature of the performance? You can tweak the code as much as you want, but it wont make much different if you are calling a database or a web service.

Comment: @dave If you are the database or web service it will. Project will require lots of number crunching and data manipulation.

Comment: @JeremyFrench Not so for web services. Most web services are written in high level languages precisely _because_ their execution times are negligible compared to the time it takes to transport the data.

Comment: Two words: Nim and Felix. Absolutely excellent performance and very high-level.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is a language in development called [The Rust Programming Language](http://rust-lang.org) which pursues similar goals as C++ does, notably zero-cost abstractions and fine control over memory management. That said, it is perhaps the most notable upcoming candidate despite being still very young.

Apart from Rust there really aren't any other popular alternatives which compile to native code. There's Delphi and D too, of course, but they aren't as fast, popular or used. Google's Go language could be a candidate, but it's still very young and aims for a bit different domain.

However, do note that C#(assuming Microsoft platform) and Java might not be all that slow even though they run on top of a virtual machine; the just-in-time compilation of code can do some optimizations which traditional ahead-of-time compilers aren't capable of applying due to lack of information of the program state and environment.

Frankly I would personally not consider C to be a candidate if C++ is an option, mainly because of the fact that modern C++ is safer, works at higher level of abstraction, is more expressive and has practically no performance loss over C(in some cases C++ is notably faster). Simply put, C++ provides everything that C provides and more. Most of the C functionality is considered to be "deprecated" and better, safer, faster and more intuitive alternatives are provided by the C++ standard library.

Comment: Really? That is quite scary, I would ask why but that is probably to subjective and argumentative

Comment: I wouldn't say the C functionality is "deprecated", in an official sense - just that there's almost no reason to ever use C library functions, raw pointers or C-arrays in C++.

Comment: maybe except in automotive industry where you need small programs to do small tasks

Comment: +1 for talking against the 'compilation is required for performance' false assumption.

Comment: personally i would like to add the fact that C++ has a big downside: the lack of a standard ABI and sometimes this is a big downside when you are looking for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: @user827992 - lack of an ABI is only a problem if you want to take your code compiled for x86 and run it on ARM (or similar). Nobody does that - they just recompile for the different platforms, so the lack of a standard ABI is not an issue. Now, between compilers on the same platform... that can be an issue.

Comment: @gbjbaanb try to compile with Visual Studio and with MinGW under Windows and good luck with that :| try also to convince a person that gives you a compiled library compiled with one of this tools that doesn't know nothing about ABIs that he is wrong and he should give you the source of that library or learn how to recompile and give the right specs. the horror, sometimes.

Comment: SML derivitives (MLton, SMLNJ) and Haskell(GHC) do compile to native code. Java can be translated to native code with java subpart of GCC.

Comment: @paxRoman: you can write small programs in C++, and write them more safely than you can in C.

Comment: @permeakra: There are tons of languages that can be compiled to native code, like Fortran, Ada, Pascal, OCaml or Eiffel. But none of them are that popular, and that's what zxcdw said.

Comment: @kevincline I agree with you, but in many cases my colleagues that work in automotive do use C. I am a Java - JavaScript - Python programmer, so I use C/C++ only when needed...

Comment: @nikie I doubt that java is unpopular. And ML family is good anti-boilerplate solution.

Comment: @permeakra: I doubt Java-to-native compilers (the non-JIT-variety) are very popular. And isn't "anti-boilerplate" just another word for unpopular? ;-)

Comment: @nikie you say, gcc is unpopular 0_o ? No. However humans are morons and usually are too dumb to recognize their own blessing.

Comment: @nikie anyway, 4 programmers I know via social networks use haskell for their projects and they are very good programmer.

Comment: @permeakra: Are you just arguing for arguing's sake? I can't see how your comments are on topic. Although the bit about morons was quite funny.

Comment: @nikie My point is that appellations to 'language popularity' are at least questionable when one considers language, as there is no good metric for it, eliminating such factors like legacy and idiocy and considering not-published projects. Examples of valid metrics for languages are performance on concrete task type, code density, modularity and readability, availability on target platform, implementation stability and quality and existence of libraries for some concrete (required in given work) tasks.

Comment: @nickie I also should say, that \many languages considered unpopular are surprisingly wide-spread and practical, even if they are coming from egg-headed. For example, ghc haskell has excellent support for concurrency, surprisingly effective web server and interesting web-framework in style of RoR, making it practical for web programming.

Comment: `There really aren't any other popular languages which compile to native code` - er, what about Objective-C?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson As far as I'm aware, Objective-C's popularity is non-existent outside Apple's platform.

Comment: I like to see some citations here for saying D is not as fast as C or C++.

Comment: @GaryWilloughby I worded the phrase badly; my intention was not to say D would be (notably) slower than C or C++(in general, because of language-design decisions), rather than it's not 1) Popular 2) at least any faster than C or C++. Although, it is my impression that there's no D implementation which would outperform(or even get that close to) any of the mainstream(MS, GCC, Intel) C or C++ implementations on a regular basis. This is based on my earlier perception of the data at Alioth language shootout.

Comment: @zxcdw: All implementations of D share backends with implementations of C++ (dmd with dmc, gdc with g++ and ldc with clang). It has slight disadvantage that it needs conservative garbage collector, which is not as fast as generational one (the garbage collector is what keeps Java fast despite the huge overhead incurred by lack of value types), but it can still keep up with explicit memory management in many cases (and of course in D you can avoid the collector if you don't want it).

Answer (score 19):

> If C++ is a different beast than it was 15 years ago, I would consider it, I guess I had an assumption that it had some inherent problems.

15 years ago, there was no C++ standard. The second one has been published last year. C++ best practices changed a lot in the 5 years after the publication of the 98 standard, and they are changing again with the publication of the 11 one.

Answer (score 19):

There is also [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29), which compiles to native code, and is portable across various platforms within the limits of its standard library. The language is alive and well, with the most recent language standard update currently underway (known as Ada 2012).

Quick summary for those unfamiliar with Ada:

- Strongly-typed
- Built-in support for concurrency
- Object-oriented or procedural, depending on your requirements
- Supported by GNU toolchain (GCC contains Ada frontend)
- Excellent also for software development, i.e. when you need to directly interface with hardware
- Supports generic programming (generic packages, procedures, functions)
- Features support large-scale software development (packages, child packages, separate compilation, strict distinction between specification and implementation)

Comment: Not to mention Ada Tasks (Parallelisation!)

Comment: +1: I have tried to learn some Ada and I think it is a very robust and clean language. A pity that there are not so many jobs as for other programming languages.

Comment: Good mention, I was looking for something more 'modern' but I had forgotten about Ada

Comment: @Jeremy French: What features are you looking for in a more 'modern' language that Ada does not offer?

Answer (score 15):

C/C++ is rather long in the tooth.... this is a *good thing*. It implies that they were designed well enough (ahem) that they are still very usable, that many people use them for everyday tasks, and that you will find a large body of developers whop are experts in them. Maturity is something to be treasured.

If you spend all your time looking for something new, just because its new and think therefore that is must somehow be better, you're in for a lot of disappointment. This applies to software languages, GUI systems (take note, Microsoft and Gnome) and lovers (take note, young ladies :) )

Now admittedly, if your experience of C++ is 20 years old, when C++ code was generally coded like C, then maybe its time to re-evaluate the language, all the features that were there in the day that were never quite used are used a lot more today, and a few standardisation efforts have expanded the language a little to make it appear much different from those old C-style developments. Not that C is bad too - its a perfect language for many types of coding task too!

Comment: I think C and C++ exemplify Hoare's comment on software design: either make it so simple there are obviously no deficiencies, or make it so complicated there are no obvious deficiencies.

Comment: How are repeated security vulnerabilities due to some form of buffer exploit a "good thing", regardless of how old or entrenched a language is? And, is this really different than arguing continuation of an established marriage after repeated abuse?

Comment: @user2864740 what you're suggesting is get a divorce because the wife is old and you want a new, exciting model... I say you stick with what you have because you know the foibles and quirks.  How many of the new, cool, languages solve problems like buffer overflow and then turn out to have subtle ways of overflowing buffers? So what's better - the overflow you can avoid by not being lazy or using the right construct, or the one that you fall into because you didn't know was there?

Comment: @gbjbaanb No, I never said that. I was drawing a simile specifically to *damage caused* by not improving the context of situations. I'm generally quite rational and not prone to "fanboi" selection of trending topics or tools (this is just my nature). Furthermore, C and C++ are different languages; yet they are both justified for the same blanketing reason. And that *is* the problem with such.

Comment: @TMN So where do you see C++ there?

Answer (score 13):

Why people always insist on looking for new languages?

C++:

- Is the number 4 language by TIOBE, but stomps all competition if combined with C
- Has lots of frameworks
- Is very easy to code in
- Is very easy to tune
- Is very performant
- Is very safe
- Has a very good industry support
- Is cross platform
- Doesn't need extra VMs/Frameworks/deployment mess if done correctly
- Will easily land you a job
- Has all the necessary stuff to build .so/.dll to launch on very old systems
- Easy to troubleshoot
- Very expressive
- Very dynamic
- and bunch of other interesting stuff

The only downside of C++ is that you have to learn a bit. That's it.

Compare that to other languages which are one or more of:

- Narrowly supported (OCML, Fortran, ...)
- Slow (Java, Javascript)
- Experimental (Silverlight)
- A moving target (.NET 1/2/3/4/5? which one is the last one now?)
- Platform locked (.NET)
- Have poor framework support (Fortran)
- Has small communities (anything outside top 10)
- Are nightmare to troubleshoot (Anything with high-level fool-proof concepts and stuff)
- Needs 500MB of preintallation on customers machine (JVM/.NETVM)

IMHO, the less languages we will use and support, the better the situation will be.

This causes automatic improvements in frameworks for the language, support, documentation, standardization committees work, better books, more knowledge, easier to support software, better patterns, longer language support cycles and more skilled code written in the language.

I know people will downvote this, but think about it, really.

Comment: (1) "Narrowly supported": C++ was also narrowly supported at the beginning. (2) "A moving target": What about C++03, C++11?

Comment: (3) "Slow": depends on what you do with them. (4) "Platform locked": c.f. mono.

Comment: C++ “is very easy to code in” is just ridiculously wrong, sorry. It’s an incredibly hard language to learn and even if you use modern C++ idioms and eschew pointers you will be faced with tons of puzzling compiler and runtime errors before getting the hang of it. And even after you’ve mastered it, the syntax gets in the way quite often. Safe C++ often uses a mess of nested templates which generate huge amounts of boilerplate code.

Comment: perhaps, because some peoples read c++ fqa at last? (google for it)

Comment: Very expressive and very dynamic do not sound like typical C++ traits, comparing to dynamic languages.

Comment: @KonradRudolph rubbish, its not that bad. Its slightly more difficulty to learn than C# or Java, what with all their interfaces and properties and so on. Where you might be correct is thinking its difficult to learn everything (ie all the super advanced features) of C++ as there is a lot of pretty amazing stuff you can do with it, but 99% of coders don't need to learn that, not at first anyway.

Comment: Runtime polymorphism (virtual) + compile time polymorphism (templates) + STL. And it allows you to do any of that stuff. And it's really easy. I don't know why people complain that it's hard. Just read a few books, like Effective C++, C++ Programming and Practice, everything will clear up.

Comment: @gbjbaanb “slightly more difficult to learn” is, once again, ridiculously off the mark. Sorry. I’ve been programming all those languages for years, I clearly prefer C++ (and do most serious programming in it) but saying that it’s easy is just totally misleading. And I’m not talking about fancy metaprogramming stuff, I’m talking about compiler errors produced by run-of-the-mill code, caused by name hiding, ADL, `const` correctness issues and stuff like that. Anybody who has read *Effective C++* (as Coder claims to have) and maintains that C++ is easy has a mental disconnect.

Comment: @Coder: you answered your own question: because in most other languages, I do not need to "read a few books" in order to get it. A trained monkey can practically write a Java or C# program. In C++, you have to read a few books, as you say. Really, whether or not C++ is "easy" is subjective. But it is obviously true that C++ is much, much harder than most other mainstream languages. You might still find it easy, but let's not pretend that other languages are not *easier*

Comment: @jalf: Programming is not easy, if you can write a Java program after reading how syntax works, you're doing it wrong, you shouldn't be in this profession! Programmer has to know what happens on all levels once he writes `foo.DoStuff()` anything else and 1) your program has a bug 2) it's a maintenance/extensibility nightmare.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: name hiding is trivial really, never ran into this issue over 10+ years. ADL, you can create some problems with it, but again, hasn't been an issue in my career, const correctness is actually very neat, once you use it from ground up. It works, what else do you need? Ok, there are fancy const * const * const constructs, but if you write code like that, it's your problem. So what exactly in Effective C++ scared you so much?

Comment: @Coder Really, did you read c++ FQA?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't say its ridiculously easy, its not, but like most things it's not so hard its incomprehensible to a programmer. Sure, other languages can be coded almost without thinking, but if you do that, you're writing the kind of code that gave VB a bad name. A little bit of learning is required for them all, just with C++ you have to do that little bit before, not after, you can write your first app.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe its because we're C++ coders that all other languages seem easy :) but take a n00b and ask them the difference between java's inherit and extends, or a C# delegate, or ask me how Ruby on Rails handled the linkage between a view and a model. All these things need a little learning, just like the basics of C++, but I don't think the difference between the amount required is that great, not for the basics at least.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I’m a C++ programmer. Once again, I don’t think C++ is easy. And this comment thread got some frowns from the C++ chat as well. So it’s not that. And the difference between C++ gotchas and other languages’ gotchas is that if you don’t know about them in other languages, you’ll probably be fine. In C++, you’re toast. And *even if* you know about them, you can still get several screen pages of compile errors for a single error (happened to me again today). And even though the error was simple to fix (a typo), it takes time to parse through all that.

Comment: @permeakra Reading the FQA will damage your brain, don’t do it. The “info” there is almost always uninformative spittle with less value than the virtual paper that it’s written on.

Comment: When has a popular language ever been good? PHP is hugely popular and no serious person thinks it's a "good" language, even for its niche. The only "good" thing about popular languages are that there are lots of libraries to make certain domains easier to program in.

C++ itself is fraught with frustration.

Comment: C++ is an abomination that should have never seen the light of day

Comment: "IMHO, the less languages we will use and support, the better the situation will be." sounds awfully insecure and like that's the only language you could feel confident in. It's **great** that we have several other languages which are miles ahead C++ in their domains. Heck, I loathe PHP, but imagine using C++ for building websites! Or using C++ as a functional language substitute, or using C++ for scripting, etc... C++ only exists because of heavy support from MS, because it's not that popular in platforms other than Windows, and even king-of-performance Google uses more *Java* than C++.

Comment: C++ isn't that difficult to learn , sure it takes a good amount of time as well as some good books to understand it but most folks compare it to new dynamic languages that come in front for 3-4 years as buzzwords and tend to disappear soon. C++ is by far most expressive language apart from c , that I am aware of. It dosen't demands a huge runtime , gives you pointers ( and please don't use them if you don't want them) and helps you understand a lot more than new languages. Most of you are just scaring away new developers from c++ by stating that it is far worst language ,cannot be maintained..

Comment: continued: and difficult to understand. Sure it takes time to understand c++ first , but then why do people who code in ROR come back to something that's close to metal? Why do they turn their back?And then f--king  buzzwords like asynchronous , evented ,mvc and appear and all those hipster developers think that their language will **webscale** and do sh** because they're powered by new buzzwords , clearly forgetting that those are just design patterns and nothing is new with them. Those design patterns can be applied to c++ as well and many are built with c++.I'm not intending to bash other..

Comment: continued2: langauges here ,but this BS has to stop.You think c++ is shit because it carries a huge baggage of backward compatiblity? Ask angular users who just cringed and lost their temper when Ag2 was declared.Other languages are good to have when they're are required. If I need a quick chat ,I won't actually rewrite all of it in c++/c ,I could fire a nodejs server and write 5-6 pages of code and deploy it.But does that means c++ is bad? Hell no. Every langauge has its dis/-advantages and you've to make that choice.For me c++ is still one beautiful langauge and I'll continue to write in it.

Comment: Really, this does not answer the original question of "What more modern alternatives are there to C for writing high performance code compiled code?"

Comment: You use "very easy" very easily. Calling C++, the hardest language out there (compared to all the others), very easy, is dumb nuts. Sorry for being rude, but you called for it :)

Answer (score 9):

I am not a big expert of this language, but I think [OCaml](https://ocaml.org) could be an interesting option to look at.

OCaml is a compiled, functional / object-oriented language.
For a performance comparison with C++ see [C++ vs OCaml: Ray tracer comparison](https://www.ffconsultancy.com/languages/ray_tracer/comparison.html).
Of course, this is a very specific example and one should do more extensive testing to have a better feeling of OCaml's performance.

Comment: Can the downvoter please give a hint as to how this answer can be improved? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Current standard of C++ is [**C++11**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), which was published in 2011. So it's not 20 years old standard. And there have been numerous standards in between. Each of them introducing numerous performance improvements.

Compilers also have been constantly improving. They are far better at optimizing, than they used to be.

Executable formats have also improved, 20 years ago you had [a.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), now you have [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Overall, suggestion that C++ didn't change in 20 year cannot be further from the truth.

Also, keep in mind, that C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: My assumption was that something that was first conceived 20 years ago would have inherent architectural limitations which could only be improved with a blank slate. I think this assumption may have been wrong.

Comment: @JeremyFrench: Like the x86 architecture?

Comment: @TMN is that proving or disproving my assumption?

Comment: The original x86 architecture was a nasty compromise between backwards compatability with the 8080 and a set of features to compete with the 68000 and NS32032.  Segmented memory (with "far" and "near" pointers), only 4 general-purpose registers, variable-length instruction encoding, over 50 flavors of JMP instruction, a multiplexed tri-state system bus...  And yet today, that same basic design is going stronger than ever, after many "superior" clean-slate designs (Alpha, MIPS, PowerPC) failed to displace it.

Comment: @JeremyFrench nope, your assumption was not wrong, at least in the case of C++. C++ 11 features are definitely useful; however, at this point they are just more crap on the crap pile. They try to build in features of modern languages, but to cope with the existing C++ mess, they must have exceptions, and those exceptions will have exceptions and so on and so forth.

Comment: @weberc2: Ok. To clean up the thread I have deleted my question. You may want to do the same. I will delete this comment afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

When you say your project is performance sensitive, do you mean every line of code of it? Or, like normal, is there a smaller percentage that is performance criticial while the rest of it is your ordinary run of the mill business code?

After you answer that, what is the bigger risk for your project: that the end result is too slow, or that you never finish it in the first place?

Assuming you answer the second for both, you should develop in a higher level language that supports native interop (Python, Ruby, the .Net Family all have this). First, finish the project. Then profile, optimize, rinse, repeat. Only after that, consider reqriting choice segment of your application in native code and integrating that native code with your finished product.

Comment: Once it's Java, you can't salvage it if it's too slow.

Comment: @Coder Java has a FFI (JNI) which allows you to 'wreak havoc' in your language of choice. So if you have designed the interfaces well, you can just replace a Java implementation with a native one. The Java platform is well thought.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what your product is going to do.  If performance is really critical, then the go-to language of choice is [still FORTRAN](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1820518).  I also wouldn't rule out Java -- it's used in many high-volume financial trading applications.  Erlang is worth a look if your problem domain requires high concurrency.  Objective-C is nice, although I don't know how well supported it is outside the Apple ecosystem (beyond compilers and basic runtime).  I've also heard good things about Haskell's performance, but I'm not sure whether that's absolute performance or just performance relative to other functional languages.

Comment: every finance job I've looked at want C/C++ developers, not Java. From experience with Java, I can't see any that are high performance unless you throw masses of hardware at it.

Comment: There are a lot of Java trading systems in operation on Wall Street and at various investment banks in the US and UK.  It's also used pretty heavily at the Chicago Mercantile Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but a friend of my swears by [Cython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) which lets you use C style primitives in performance critical parts of your code while keeping the general python syntax and being able to take full advantage of pythons higher level constructs to reduce development time everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

[Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala) is similar to Java and C#, compiles to native code (or C source code if you prefer), and is [very fast](https://code.google.com/p/vala-benchmarks/wiki/BenchResults). It does require GLib for its object-oriented bits, and it's written by Linux hackers for Linux hackers, so if your domain is Windows it may not be very good.

Answer (score 2):

[Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_C) is modern, compiled alternative to straight C and C++. It has both garbage-collected and deterministic memory management and the message-passing OO runtime has been optimized for performance.

It is available through GCC and CLang and there are application libraries such as GNUStep and Cocotron which work on various platforms.

If you're doing high-performance work, I'm going to assume that's kind of number-crunching or other divide-and-conquer work instead of UI, so that means you could do the UI in whatever language is easiest for you, e.g. HTML via a mini http server.